# Why is the OnAttached() method not firing for Avalonia Control AttachedProperty when DataContext is dynamically assigned?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, avaloniaui

I am using the **Avalonia TextEditor**. I've created an attached property to support binding of Text with my ViewModel. The issue I'm seeing is a bit strange.

The **TextEditor** is contained in a TabControl page in a UserControl.
When the app initially loads, the **TextEditorDocumentBindingBehavior.OnAttached()** method fires. It contains a NULL ViewModel and returns.

This makes sense because: SelectedItem.SelectedChildItem is initially NULL.

Once the Parent UserControl is loaded, SelectedItem.SelectedChildItem has a value and the converter method fires to return the required ViewModel for TextEditor's DataContext.

During the assignment, the **OnAttached()** method does not fire and I don't see the text from my ViewModel populated in the TextEditor control.

If I go to the 2nd tab and click back to the 1st tab (containing TextEditor), the
OnAttach() method fires and I see the ViewModel text (Source) appear in the control.

Can someone help explain what's going on here?
Do I somehow need to force the OnAttach() to get fired?
When dynamically assigning the the ViewModel a DataContext in the containing Parent control,
is there a way to make sure the OnAttach() method fires so my initial values are loaded?

**Here are the properties from my ViewModel:**

```
[Reactive] public string? Source {get; set;} = string.Empty;
public string? SourceText
{
    get { return Source; }
    set
    {
        if (value != Source)
        {
            Source = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the code for TextEditorProperties:**

```
public class TextEditorProperties
{
    public static readonly AttachedProperty<string> BindTextToProperty =
        AvaloniaProperty.RegisterAttached<TextEditor, string>("BindTextTo", typeof(TextEditorProperties));
    public static string GetBindTextTo(TextEditor p_textEditor)
    {
        return p_textEditor.GetValue(BindTextToProperty);
    }
    public static void SetBindTextTo(TextEditor p_textEditor, string p_value)
    {
        p_textEditor.SetValue(BindTextToProperty, p_value);
    }
}
```

**Here is the code for the behavior implementation:**

```
public class TextEditorDocumentBindingBehavior : Behavior<TextEditor>
{
    private TextDocument? TextEditorDocument;
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        if (AssociatedObject is TextEditor textEditor)
        {
            if (AssociatedObject.DataContext is MyViewModel viewModel)
            {
                var propertyToBind = TextEditorProperties.GetBindTextTo(AssociatedObject);
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyToBind))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("BindTextTo property cannot be null or empty.");
                }
                TextEditorDocument = new TextDocument();
                TextEditorDocument.TextChanged += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    var property = viewModel.GetType().GetProperty(propertyToBind);
                    if (property != null)
                    {
                        if (sender is not TextDocument textDocument) return;
                        property.SetValue(viewModel, textDocument.Text);
                    }
                };
                var initialText = GetInitialText(viewModel, propertyToBind);
                TextEditorDocument.Text = initialText;
                AssociatedObject.TextArea.Document = TextEditorDocument;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        if (TextEditorDocument != null)
        {
            TextEditorDocument.TextChanged -= (sender, e) => { };
            TextEditorDocument = null;
        }
    }

    private string? GetInitialText(MyViewModel p_viewModel, string p_propertyToBind)
    {
        var property = p_viewModel.GetType().GetProperty(p_propertyToBind);
        if (property != null)
        {
            return property.GetValue(p_viewModel) as string;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}

<!-- Parent UserControl Definition  -->
<UserControl>
<TabControl>
<TabItem Header="One" >
    <Grid>
        <AvaloniaEdit:TextEditor Name="TextEditorTest"
                                 behaviors:TextEditorProperties.BindTextTo="SourceText"
                                 FontFamily="Cascadia Code,Consolas,Menlo,Monospace">
            <AvaloniaInteractive:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:TextEditorDocumentBindingBehavior/>
            </AvaloniaInteractive:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </AvaloniaEdit:TextEditor>
    </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</TabItem>

<TabItem Header="Two"> </TabItem>
</TabControl>
</UserControl>  
    
<!-- MyUserControl Definition  -->  
 <MyUserControl >
     <MyUserControl.DataContext>
         <Binding Path="SelectedItem.SelectedChildItem" Converter="{StaticResource SelectedChildItemToMyViewModelConverter}"/>  
     </MyUserControl.DataContext> 
 </MyUserControl>
```

Comment: I figured out the issue. When the UserControl's DataContext changes dynamically due to Converter, the TextEditor does not have the behavior attached. If I implement OnDataContextChanged() call back I can intercept, and assign the TextEditor's DataContext (if nul)l, then create an instance of the behavior and attach it to the TextEditor control

Comment: Here is a code snippet:
protected override void OnDataContextChanged(EventArgs e)
{
 base.OnDataContextChanged(e);

 if (DataContext != null)
 {
  var textEditor = this.FindControl<TextEditor>("MyTextEditor");
  if (textEditor?.DataContext == null)
  {
   textEditor!.DataContext = this.DataContext;
   var textEditorBehavior = new TextEditorDocumentBindingBehavior();
   textEditorBehavior.Attach(textEditor);
  }
 }
}